# Rx - maximum number of items over a sliding time window

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Is there an existing Rx operator that allows doing the following?

- Allow only X number of items over a given period, which is a sliding time window.
- The items over the capacity should be buffered for the next push.

For example, allow a maximum of 1000 items in 10 seconds throughout the observable sequence. The important point is that those 10 seconds is a sliding window, meaning it can be any 10 seconds throughout the timeline.

I looked up buffer and window operators but does not look like the correct ones. I am okay to write my own but just wanted to confirm if there is anything existing already.

Comment: Can you please try to explain the important point a little more? What does "those 10 seconds is a sliding window, meaning it can be any 10 seconds throughout the timeline" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity Sure, let me try with an example. First 10 seconds = 900 items, Next 10 seconds = 800 items. At first look, it would seem that we should allow all the items to pass through. But it is possible that there were 800 items pushed in 8-9th second and 400 items pushed in 11-12th second. So, this will fail the criteria as there are more than 1000 items in 2-12 seconds window. 
If I have to rephrase - Whenever a new item arrives, check the last 10 seconds if it is going over the capacity. If not, let it pass. If yes then wait for the exact time when it is eligible to be sent.

Comment: There is no such operator and the behavior you describe is complicated to achieve with many possible corner cases. Why do you need this peculiar pattern? What was the original requirement you tried to implement this way?

Comment: @akarnokd Unfortunately, cannot give more details due to privacy concerns but trust me the requirements are exactly this. I would have simplified it if it was possible. Anyways, given you are the Rx expert, I will take your word and just implement it myself. Thank you.